# Mix :select with :include in find method (Rails 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, include, find, ruby-on-rails-2

I have 2 models, `User` and `UserProfile`. A `user` has_one user_profile and a `user_profile` belongs_to user.

**1) Find without select**

This query in console works fine, and take only 2 SQL queries.

```
>> User.find(:all, :limit => 10, :include => [ :user_profile ])
```

```
User Load (0.3ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` LIMIT 10
UserProfile Load (0.3ms)   SELECT `user_profiles`.* FROM `user_profiles`
      WHERE (`user_profiles`.user_id IN (1,2,3,...))
```

**2) Find with select on `user` model**

I can select columns from `User` model, with

```
>> User.find(:all, :select => '`users`.id, `users`.last_name',
     :limit => 10, :include => [ :user_profile ])
```

```
User Load (0.3ms)   SELECT `users`.id, `users`.last_name FROM `users` LIMIT 10
UserProfile Load (0.2ms)   SELECT `user_profiles`.* FROM `user_profiles`
      WHERE (`user_profiles`.user_id IN (17510,18087,17508,17288...))
```

Everything works fine. Note that I must set `users.id` in the user selected columns, because the second query doesn't work (return NULL).

**3) Find with select on `user_profile` model**

But when I try to select columns from `UserProfile` model, I got only 1 query, which doesn't take care of my `:select`

```
>> User.find(:all,
     :select => '`users`.id, `users`.last_name, `user_profiles`.permalink',
     :limit => 10, :include => [ :user_profile ])
```

```
User Load Including Associations (0.6ms) SELECT `users`.`id` AS t0_r0,
  `users`.`login` AS t0_r1, ....
  `user_profiles`.`id` AS t1_r0,
  `user_profiles`.`birth_date` AS t1_r1,
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `user_profiles` ON user_profiles.user_id = users.id LIMIT 10
```

As you can see, the Rails query contains fiels from users and fields from user_profiles that I didn't select.

**4) Join method**

Codeit purpose a method with `join` function :

```
user_details = User.find(:all,
   :select => '`users`.id, `users`.last_name, `user_profiles`.permalink',
   :limit => 10, :joins => [ :user_profile ]
)
```

```
User Load (0.2ms) SELECT `users`.id, `users`.last_name, `user_profiles`.permalink
   FROM `users`
   INNER JOIN `user_profiles` ON user_profiles.user_id = users.id
   LIMIT 10
```

This solution works fine with SQL queries, but doesn't make 'link' between User and User Profile. 10 new queries are needed, while the method 1 and 2 make only 2 SQL queries.

```
 user_details.map(&:user_profile).map(&:permalink)
 UserProfile Load (0.3ms)   SELECT * FROM `user_profiles` WHERE (`user_profiles`.user_id = 1) LIMIT 1
 UserProfile Load (0.2ms)   SELECT * FROM `user_profiles` WHERE (`user_profiles`.user_id = 2) LIMIT 1
 ... (10 times) ...
 UserProfile Load (0.3ms)   SELECT * FROM `user_profiles` WHERE (`user_profiles`.user_id = 10) LIMIT 1
```

Is there a right syntax to have same results than the 2 first queries, but with a `:select` witch select only a few columns of my models ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `join`:

```
User.find(:all,
 :select => '`users`.id, `users`.last_name, `user_profiles`.permalink',
 :limit => 10, :joins => [ :user_profile ])
```

`include` is used for `eager loading`. It is used to solve `(N+1)` queries problem for accessing user_profile when you have large `users` with `user_profile`. If you want to select `columns` of included table you need to use `join`. If you use columns of included table it will just ignored from `select` clause.

**EDIT:**

```
user_details = User.find(:all,
   :select => '`users`.id, `users`.last_name, `user_profiles`.permalink',
   :limit => 10, :joins => [ :user_profile ]
 )

user_details.map(&:permalink)
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about `joins`, but `joins` does not make the link between User and UserProfile... Then when I do your query followed by .map(&:user_profile), it takes 10 queries.

Comment: what do you mean by `doesn't link` ?? Can paste the query ?? When you use `.map(&:user_profile)` it will fire `N` queries. Thats the difference between `include` and `join`.

Comment: Why are using `map(&:user_profile)` when you selected `permalink` just do `previous_query.map(&:permalink)`. I guess it works without firing extra queries.